# Downloading S3 Object with PreSignedUrl

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a webpage in which, when the user clicks a button, a download starts. The files are stored in an S3 bucket. After some searching I came to the following js code:

```
// Handle click event of "Download" dropdown item
var downloadBtn = document.querySelector('#dropdownMenuButton2 + ul li:nth-child(2) a');

downloadBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
// Get the selected files from the grid
var grid = document.getElementById('grid').ej2_instances[0];
var selectedFiles = grid.getSelectedRecords();
if (selectedFiles.length === 0) {
    alert('Please select at least one file.');
    return;
}

// Create an array to store the file names
var filePaths = [];

// Extract the file paths from the selected files
selectedFiles.forEach(function(file) {
    filePaths.push(file.Path);
});

// Create an AJAX request
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/Projects/DownloadFiles', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // Request was successful, handle the response
    var signedUrls = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    // Loop through the signed URLs and initiate the download
    signedUrls.forEach(function(signedUrl, index) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = signedUrl;
        // Set the Content-Disposition header value
        link.setAttribute('download', contentDisposition); //contentDisposition = "attachment; filename = filename"
        link.click();
        });
    })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });
    } else {
    // Request failed, handle the error
    console.error('Error:', xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
    }
};

xhr.onerror = function() {
    // Request error, handle the error
    console.error('Request error:', xhr.statusText);
};

// Send the file paths as JSON in the request body
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(filePaths));
});

// Function to extract the file name from a file path
function getFileNameFromPath(filePath) {
var fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
return decodeURIComponent(fileName);
}
```

This allows my "Download" button to open the PreSignedS3Url and show the content in the browser. I want the file to be downloaded without being reddirected to any page.

Then, after more searching I tried using fetch() api.

```
...
// Loop through the signed URLs and initiate the download
        signedUrls.forEach(function(signedUrl, index) {
          fetch(signedUrl)
            .then(function(response) {
              return response.blob();
            })
            .then(function(blob) {
              var link = document.createElement('a');
              link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
              link.download = getFileNameFromPath(filePaths[index]); // Set the desired file name
              link.click();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        });
...
```

With fetch I receive the error:

*Access to fetch at 'https://mydomain.s3.amazonaws.com/presignedS3url' from origin 'https://localhost:7063' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

I changed my bucket CORS policy to allow:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

And I receive the same error, so I cannot test with fetch.

**EDIT: After adding "GET" to the allowed methods it works.
Yet, when using Response.blob(), the browser needs to fully load the response into memory before creating the Blob. This can result in a delay before the download starts, especially for larger files. This is not the solution I'm looking for since I want the download to start right away.**

I don't know if there are easier ways to get what I want but I am not being able to do so. Basically I want the user to click the "Download" button. Next, after the server side retrieves the PreSignedUrl and sends them to the client side, I want the files to be directly downloaded into the user computer, not redirect to any URL nor showing the contents in the browser. If you can help me I will be very thankful.

Comment: When you’re using JavaScript to click on the pre signed URL the browser is making a GET request. I’d start my adding GET to the list of allowed CORS methods on your S3 bucket.

Comment: If the goal is to provide a link to download, why not add a content-disposition header instead of using fetch?

Comment: @fubar I added get to CORS allowed methods, and it works now. Thank you. One thing I noticed is that when using Response.blob(), the browser needs to fully load the response into memory before creating the Blob. This can result in a delay before the download starts, especially for large files. I think this is not the solution I'm looking for since I want the download to start right away.

Comment: @AnonCoward I'm trying to add the content-disposition header. I'm reading it cannot be done in the client side. If in my server I'm only returning urls, how can I set this header?

Comment: @JoaoLima, you could set the download headers on the server response, however, you'd only be able to download one file per response.

Comment: @fubar, I'm adding to my java script the following: link.setAttribute('download', contentDisposition); where contentDisposition is a string, containing "attachment; filename = filename". Is that how you set the downlaod headers, because it's still opening the pre signed urls and not downloading the file.